# Android Floating point multiplication off by a factor 0.004739

Tags: android, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Can anyone explain to me why the `speed` calculation is off?
It is a floating point calculation. I show (below) in the log print all the factors involved.
According to my hand calculator:

> length: sqrt(3.497924^2 + (-1.134711)^2) = 3.67736881
>   speed: 1.05 * 3.67736881 = **3.86123725**

this is off by a factor 4.739 10^-3 from the printed result **3.879624**

The code:

```
        float factor = yTouch(paddle, ballBounds);
        float speed = SPEED_TRANSFER[level] * PointF.length(mSpeed.x, mSpeed.y);
        double alpha = Math.PI/2;
        double beta = Math.atan2(mSpeed.y, mSpeed.x);
        double tau = -(2*alpha+beta);
        Log.v("debug", String.format("speed(%f) mSpeed(%f,%f) transfer(%2.2f) 
            length(%f) Original tau(%3.2f)", speed, mSpeed.x, mSpeed.y, 
            SPEED_TRANSFER[level], PointF.length(mSpeed.x, mSpeed.y), tau/Math.PI));
```

The Log:

```
03-24 10:48:53.421: V/debug(3236): speed(3.879624) mSpeed(3.497924,-1.134711) transfer(1.05) length(3.677369) Original tau(-0.90)
```

**Edit**
I tried this, the direct multiplication is right.

```
Log.v("debug", "Direct multiplication:" + (1.05f * 3.677369f) );

03-24 11:49:08.687: V/debug(7644): Direct multiplication:3.8612373
```

Comment: are you sure the value of the SPEED_TRANSFER[level] = 1.05 and the PointF.length(mSpeed.x, mSpeed.y) = 3.67736881 in your code?have you try to log it?

Comment: @NAYOSO It is in the log print, scroll right

Comment: Is this multi-threaded by any chance? Is `mSpeed` changing between the calculation of `speed` and your Log line? Also, does it make a difference if you declare `factor` and `speed` as `double`?

Comment: @mtrw No, it is not multithread. I run a direct multipication test and the result is right!! So I don't know where `speed` gets its value from! I will put it in the question.

Comment: Can you print more digits of `SPEED_TRANSFER[level]` in your log line? You're looking at an error in the 3rd decimal place, but only showing 2 places of one of the factors. If `SPEED_TRANSFER[level] == 1.055` for instance the result is correct (although I would have expected this to print as `1.06` in your Log line, but that's another matter).

Comment: @mtrw You are right. The SPEED_TRANSFER is 1.055, somehow the game level changed and I did not noticed. Please post your comment as an answer if you want me to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped - don't worry about the points. To be honest, I feel a bit silly for not having asked this first :)

Comment: @mtrw And I feel silly for not having caught it myself!! A big thanks!

Comment: @mtrw, If you posted an answer people looking at the question listing could see that this one already has been answered without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you print more digits of `SPEED_TRANSFER[level]` in your log line? You're looking at an error in the 3rd decimal place, but only showing 2 places of one of the factors. If `SPEED_TRANSFER[level] == 1.055` for instance the result is correct (although I would have expected this to print as 1.06 in your Log line, but that's another matter).